# Изменение существующей записи в Realm

Tags: android, realm, realm-android

Начал своё знакомство с Realm. Создал простейшую таблицу:

```
public class NoteModel extends RealmObject {

   private String note;
   private String header;
   private Date date;

  /* геттеры и сеттеры для данных
   * ...
  */
}
```

И научился заполнять её данными. Данные вывожу с помощью RecyclerView в элементах CardView. Теперь хочу выбрать CardView и изменить данные этой записи. Как мне найти именно ту запись? В SQLite есть поле id и оно является уникальным для каждой записи, в Realm же такого нет. Мне стоит самому определить поле id в моделе? Единственная информация которую я нашёл в доках/англоязычных форумах это упоминание что для обновления информации можно воспользоваться

```
copyToRealmOrUpdate(obj);
```

или

```
insertOrUpdate(obj);
```

но я не совсем понимаю как я смогу с их помощью изменить конкретную запись.

Буду рад любой помощи/примерам с кодом/проектам с гита.

Comment: чтобы это работало, вам нужно в модели определить поле с аннотацией  @PrimaryKey, именно по значению этого поля метод будет ориентироваться — обновлять существующюю запись или создавать новую (если запись с таким значением ключа еще не создана). Из этого следует еще одна проблема, что в Realm нет автоинкремента ключа и вам придется писать собственный метод для его генерации и обеспечения уникальности, что печалит (впрочем в сети уже есть несколько реализаций)

Comment: в документации про это [вполне однозначно сказано](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/io/realm/Realm.html#copyToRealmOrUpdate-E-), аналогично смотрите и по второму методу. Какой из них использовать тоже вопрос не однозначный

Comment: public void execute(Realm bgRealm) {
                Number currentId = bgRealm.where(NoteModel.class).max("id");
                if (currentId != null){
                    currentId = currentId.intValue() + 1;
                }
                else {
                    currentId = 0;
                }
                NoteModel noteModel = bgRealm.createObject(NoteModel.class);
                noteModel.setID(currentId.intValue());
                noteModel.setHeader(header);
                noteModel.setNote(note);
                noteModel.setDate(date);
            } вот так?

Comment: метод по получению id лучше всего вынести в отдельный статический класс, типа Utils или в наследника Application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Допустим у нас есть одна модель:

```
note = "note1";
header = "header1";
date = ...;
```

К примеру, мы хотим изменить поле `header` у модели, чье поле `note` имеет значение "note1":

```
NoteModel noteModel = Realm.getDefaultInstance().where(NoteModel.class).equalTo("note", "note1").findFirst();
noteModel.setHeader("header2");
```

По идее должно сработать насколько я помню. Но лучше посмотри [оф.доку](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/). Там примеров выше крыши.

PS Забыл добавить, что сетать нужно в транзакциях. Думаю ты это прекрасно знаешь как сделать :)